# Tracking new user creation by marketing campaign

Tags: 7

I have a use case where users may be linked to any page on a D7 site with a marketing ID (bound to $_GET) and I need to write this data to a field associated with a new user once they register. I can implement this under the pretense that the user's landing page is on Register (through altering the register_form via `hook_form_{ID}_alter()`, but if s/he starts from any other page, this identifier won't be preserved if and when they eventually decide to register.

What are my options to best implement this logic across all possible states for anonymous users, while preserving any kind of GET attributes (or cookies) to indicate this source id?